# Unterschied zwischen "da" und "weil" im Nebensatz

Tags: word-usage, difference, conjunction, clauses

Ich habe heute etwas über Nebensätze gelernt. Dabei habe ich etwas nicht verstanden.

Meine Problem ist, dass ich nicht verstehe, wann man "da" und wann man "weil" benutzen muss.

Könnte mir das jemand bitte erklären?

Answer (score 13):

Die Konjunktionen *da* und *weil* sind Synonyme. Das heißt, dass sie gegeneinander ausgetauscht werden können, ohne dass sich der Sinn des Satzes dabei ändert.

> Ich bin zu spät in die Arbeit gekommen, weil mein Auto einen Defekt hatte.

hat genau dieselbe Bedeutung wie

> Ich bin zu spät in die Arbeit gekommen, da mein Auto einen Defekt hatte.

Eine Feinheit ist vielleicht noch erwähnenswert: "Da" wird häufiger benutzt, wenn der Nebensatz *vor* dem Hauptsatz steht. Dabei ist die Handlung, über die gesprochen wird, häufig bereits bekannt.

> Da mein Auto kaputt ist, werde ich heute zu spät in die Arbeit kommen.

Comment: Was auch noch wichtig ist und vor allem in der Umgangssprache oft falsch gemacht wird ist der Satzbau im mit „weil“ eingeleiteten Nebensatz. Ich meine hiermit Sätze wie „Ich komme zu spät zur Arbeit, weil ich habe verschlafen“. Dieser Fehler findet sich fast ausschließlich im gesprochenen Wort – zum Glück – und ist auch dort nur umgangssprachlich anzutreffen, aber erwähnenswert finde ich es.

Comment: @PattaFeuFeu: Nach jahrelangem Kampf gegen die Konstruktion "weil + Hauptsatz" musste ich mich vom [Duden belehren](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/newsletter/duden-newsletter-vom-30-10-09#was) lassen, dass das umgangsprachlich eben *kein* Fehler mehr ist...

Comment: @mthomas Ist ja ekelig!

Comment: Ich habe gehört, einen Satz mit "weil" anzufangen, klingt seltsamer als den mit "da" zu beginnen.

Comment: @PattaFeuFeu... ich muss leider sagen, dass ich in einigen Fällen weil+ HS sogar besser finde als weil + NS und mich BEWUSST für die "falsche" Variante entscheide... es ist einfach ein Unterschied in Betonung und Farbe.. ich glaube der Zug ist abgefahren. Das wird in 10 Jahren ganz normal sein :)

Comment: Erstaunlich, dass noch niemand auf eine subjektive Unterscheidung hinsichtlich der Stilebene eingegangen ist. Ich vermeide so gut es geht, Aussagen in der gehobenen Schriftsprache mit *weil*-Konstruktionen zu begründen, weil mir der umgangssprachliche Anklang dieses Wortes die Diktion zu sehr verwässert.

Comment: @hrrja Allerdings hast du hier gerade "weil" verwendet. :)

Comment: Das war auch nicht "gehobene Schriftsprache". ;-)

Answer (score 6):

**Summary**
They are basically interchangeable with each other, **but**

- ***weil*** is used when refering to a **important, new or unmentioned fact** and
- ***da*** is used when something is **less important, already mentioned or considered (commonly) known**.

Example:

> Das wundert mich, weil er gesagt hat, er wolle mitfahren.
>
> Da unser Garten genügend groß ist, könnten wir den Caravan dort abstellen.
>   *oder*
>   Wir könnten den Caravan in unserem Garten abstellen, da dieser genügend groß ist.

In fact one could exchange *weil* and *da* in these sentences, but naturally nobody would.

---

**Entire Source**
That's what [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Funktion/Adverbial/Kausal.html) says and it seems adequate (emphasis by me).

> Die Konjunktionen da und weil sind gegenseitig austauschbar. Es besteht aber ein kleiner Bedeutungsunterschied:
>
> Mit ***weil*** wird eher ein Grund angegeben, der **wichtig oder neu und noch unerwähnt** ist.
>
> Mit ***da*** wird eher ein Grund angegeben, der **verhältnismäßig unwichtig ist, der bereits erwähnt worden ist oder der als bekannt vorausgesetzt** wird:
>
> *Warum trinkst du nur einen Kaffee?*
>   *Ich nehme nur einen Kaffee, weil ich schon gegessen habe.*
>   [...]
>   *Da ich, wie Sie wissen, im Ausland war, antworte ich Ihnen erst jetzt.*

The last example also shows, that it is rather used in the beginning of a sentence. Note the following consequence

> Diese Tendenz ist der Grund dafür, dass auf eine direkte Frage im Allgemeinen **nur** mit *weil* geantwortet wird:
>
> *Warum kommst du erst jetzt?
>
>   – Weil ich eine Stunde im Stau gestanden habe.*

Cases where they are exchangable

> Nebenordnend zwischen Adektiven und Adverbien/Adverbialien:
>
> Die Konjunktionen da und weil können auch nebenordnend zwischen zwei Adjektiven, Adverbien oder Adverbialien stehen:
>
> eine ungenießbare, weil/da völlig versalzene Suppe
>   Die Frage kam zum falschen Zeitpunkt, weil/da zu spät.

Answer (score 2):

Ich denke, es gibt einen Unterschied, obgleich dieser nicht unbedingt bei Nebensätzen direkt auftritt:

> "Warum hast du deine Hausaufgaben nicht dabei?" - "Weil der Hund sie gefressen hat!"

"Da" wurde sich komisch anhören. Generell würde man bei Fragen nach Wieso-Weshalb-Warum mit "Weil" antworten.

Comment: Das ist aber kein inhaltlicher Unterschied, sondern um (unbewusst) von der Partikel „da“ im Hauptsatz zu unterscheiden: „Da hat der Hund doch die Hausaufgaben gefressen!“

Comment: Falsch, "Da der Hund die Hausaufgaben gefressen hat" ist schlichtweg unidiomatisches Deutsch. Dein Beispielsatz verwendet "Da" auf ganz andere Weise.

Answer (score 0):

Also wir haben gelernt, dass bei *da* ein gemeinsames Wissen als Sprechgrundlage gegeben ist, bei *weil* geht es um neue Informationen für den Hörer.

Comment: Diese Regel ist mir unbekannt. Kannst Du klarstellen, inwiefern sich mit "da" keine für den Empfänger neuen Informationen vermitteln lassen? - Eine Referenz auf eine verlässliche Quelle lasse ich auch gelten! ;)